# Solve $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= 1-(ax)^4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me solving this differential equation? I am at the beginning of studying them and I have many doubts about understanding the good method to choose.
Thanks!!

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= 1-(ax)^4$$

Answer (score 4):

The trouble here is we need to get rid of the second derivative and replace it with a first. A standard trick is to multiply both sides by $dx/dt$ and integrate

$$\int  \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} \ dt = \int \left( 1 - (ax)^4 \right) \frac{dx}{dt} \ dt$$

$$\int v \frac{dv}{dt} \ dt = \int \left( 1 - (ax)^4 \right)  \ dx $$
where $v = dx/dt$. Hence

$$\int v  \ dv = \int \left( 1 - (ax)^4 \right)  \ dx $$

or

$$\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 \ = \ x - \frac{a^4}{5}x^5 + C$$

Take the square root and you now have a separable equation. The resulting integral is a bit ugly.